# UICollectionView animation problem when cells appear during scrolling

Tags: animation, swiftui, uicollectionview, uikit

I can't seem to get rid of this animation when cells appear as shown in this video:

https://nostr.build/av/4b64e112d2c7225cd16082c0717c6bd126bf2d46e41f7df73d47176037fe9771.mov

This app is a mix of UIKit and SwiftUI, because pure SwiftUI is lacking some features that I need in relation to the scroll position and inserting new cells at the top.

It's a UICollectionView in a UIViewControllerRepresentable, and then each cell in the collection view is a SwiftUI rendered through a UIHostingConfiguration.

I am able remove all animations on my SwiftUI views with

```swift
SomeView.transaction { transaction in 
  transaction.animation = nil
}
```

But not this one, I think it is somehow configured in the UICollectionView

I think the animation is triggered because I'm using:

```swift
collectionView.selfSizingInvalidation = .enabled
```

But I can't remove that because I need it to get the cells with the correct height. I just need it to be instant, without the animation.

The full code is here:
https://github.com/nostur-com/nostur-ios-public/blob/main/Nostur/Mainfeed/SmoothList.swift